# Labeling exercises produced with tcolorbox

Tags: labels, tcolorbox

I produce exercises, in book environment, chapter by chapter, using the doc in the last version of tcolorbox. In this version, the labels are automatically produced (with the command `label={exercise@\thetcbcounter}`). I want to make my own labels, like in the previous version, by the same way as the command `label={exe:#2},`  where `#2` is the name of the label what I want to define. How can I do this ?

I give an example of a file with the data in the doc, and I use the command

`The solution of the exercise \ref{exercise@1.1} is in the page \pageref{solution@1.1}`

so I want to recall the labels (found in the .aux file !) `exercise@1.1` and `solution@1.1` by the labels `exercise:mylabel` and `solution:mylabel`, respectively.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}


 \tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{+O{}}{%
enhanced,colframe=green!20!black,colback=yellow!10!white,coltitle=green!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
\draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
(interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
label={exercise@\thetcbcounter},
attach title to upper=\quad,
after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
{\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution@\thetcbcounter}}},
lowerbox=ignored,
savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
record={\string\solution{\thetcbcounter}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
#1
}
\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
enhanced,colframe=red!20!black,colback=yellow!10!white,coltitle=red!40!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
\draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
(interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise@#1} on page~\pageref{exercise@#1}:},
phantomlabel={solution@#1},
attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}



\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}

\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( \sin((\sin x)^2) \right)’
=\cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\vspace*{1cm}
The solution of the exercise \ref{exercise@1.1} is in the page \pageref{solution@1.1}
\vspace*{1cm}
\tcbstoprecording
\tcbinputrecords

\end{document}
```

which gives after compiling with XeLatex:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code adds a mandatory argument to `exercise`. This mandatory argument is the label which will be added to `exercise:...` and `solution:...`.

The introduction of this label implied to change `label`, `after upper` and `record` option definitions in `exercise` tcolorbox. Also previous `#1` has been changed to `#2`.

In `solution` box there are no new arguments but changes in `title` and `phantomlabel`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
        {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution:#1}}},
    lowerbox=ignored,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=red!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=red!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise:#1} on page~\pageref{exercise:#1}:},
    phantomlabel={solution:#1},
    attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}

\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( \sin((\sin x)^2) \right)’
=\cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\vspace*{1cm}
The solution of the exercise \ref{exercise:Ex1} is in the page \pageref{solution:Ex1}
\vspace*{1cm}
\tcbstoprecording
\tcbinputrecords

\end{document}
```

The result and auxiliary files don't change, only the contents in `aux` file will show new label syntax and values.

[image]

Comment: Your works are excellent. Best regards.

Comment: I published another question, related to this one, and your help is wellcome. Would you see this link please http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350028/solutions-of-exercises-produced-with-tcolorbox