# Solutions of exercises produced with tcolorbox

Tags: sectioning, tcolorbox, exercises

I produce exercises with solutions, in `book` class, chapter by chapter, using the doc in the last version of `tcolorbox`. I want to produce the answers grouped in the end of the book. I can do this using `\tcbstartrecording` in the beginning of the file and `\tcbstoprecording` in the end of the file. At the end, the command `\tcbinputrecords` gives the answers in the same order. I want to obtain the answers grouped by chapter, with a title for each group, "Solutions of the exercises of the chapter 1" for those of the first chapter, "Solutions of the exercises of the chapter 2" for those of the second chapter, and so on..

I give the page 4 of the pdf file what I obtain. I want the title "Solutions of the exercises of the chapter 1" before the box titled "Solution of Exercise 1.1 on page 1" and the title "Solutions of the exercises of the chapter 2"  before the box titled "Solution of Exercise 2.1 on page 3". How can I do this?

Here is the `.tex` file used:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
        {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution:#1}}},
    lowerbox=ignored,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=red!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=red!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise:#1} on page~\pageref{exercise:#1}:},
    phantomlabel={solution:#1},
    attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}

\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( \sin((\sin x)^2) \right)’
=\cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\vspace*{1cm}
The solution of the exercise \ref{exercise:Ex1} is in the page \pageref{solution:Ex1}
\vspace*{1cm}
%\tcbstoprecording
%\tcbinputrecords
\chapter{The second chapter}

%\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex2}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right)’
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\vspace*{1cm}
The solution of the exercise \ref{exercise:Ex2} is in the page \pageref{solution:Ex2}
\vspace*{1cm}
\tcbstoprecording
\newpage
\section{Solutions of the exercices}
\tcbinputrecords
\end{document}
```

and the page 4 of its compilation with Xelatex:

[image]

Comment: Your file does not compile out of the box -- it has explicit font settings (not everybody has those fonts) and tries to write to a directory named `solutions`. Please reduce your document to a MWE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to prepend the `\chapter` command to write some information about the chapter into the record file. This will fail for the first chapter since the recording has not started then.

It will also fail if the chapter number is reset.

Since the prepending occurs before the chapter number is increased, I've decided to `trick` `\c@chapter` using a number increased by one within a `TeX` group, so the counter value is not really changed but `\thechapter` will use the tricked value for while and apply the correct format as defined for `\thechapter`. This is better than using something like `\arabic{chapter}` etc, in my point of view.

Change the `\solutionchapterformat` macro at will to produce any nice/fancy heading of the solution-chapter-group (but leave the `\bgroup...
\egroup`)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% Formatting command as a 'headline' of the solutions of chapter X
\NewDocumentCommand{\solutionchapterformat}{m}{%
  \noindent \bgroup\bfseries Solutions of the exercises of the chapter #1\egroup%
}
\makeatletter


\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \begingroup
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0\relax
  \tcbrecord{\string\clearpage}% Write a clearpage after the first chapter for each new chapter
  \fi
  \c@chapter \numexpr\c@chapter+1% Increase the count register `\@chapter` by one to trick `\thechapter` using the 'correct' chapter number
  \tcbrecord{%
    \solutionchapterformat{\thechapter}}%
  \endgroup
}{}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\extrasolutioncontent}{+m}{%
  \tcbrecord{Extra solution stuff\par}% Remove this later on!
  \tcbrecord{\detokenize{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\fetchsolutions}{%
%For the first chapter
\begingroup
\c@chapter1%
\solutionchapterformat{\thechapter}%
\endgroup% Now get the rest of the stuff
\tcbinputrecords
}
\makeatother

%\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{english}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setsansfont{Arial}
%\setmonofont{Courier New}


\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
        {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution:#1}}},
    lowerbox=ignored,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=red!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=red!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise:#1} on page~\pageref{exercise:#1}:},
    phantomlabel={solution:#1},
    attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}

\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( \sin((\sin x)^2) \right)’
=\cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\vspace*{1cm}
The solution of the exercise \ref{exercise:Ex1} is in the page \pageref{solution:Ex1}
\vspace*{1cm}
%\tcbstoprecording
%\tcbinputrecords
\chapter{The second chapter}

%\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex2}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right)’
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\vspace*{1cm}
The solution of the exercise \ref{exercise:Ex2} is in the page \pageref{solution:Ex2}
\vspace*{1cm}

\chapter{The third chapter}

\begin{exercise}{Ex3}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right)’
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\vspace*{1cm}
The solution of the exercise \ref{exercise:Ex3} is in the page \pageref{solution:Ex3}
\vspace*{1cm}


\extrasolutioncontent{$\textcolor{blue}{E=mc^2}$}

\begin{exercise}{Ex31}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right)’
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\vspace*{1cm}
The solution of the exercise \ref{exercise:Ex31} is in the page \pageref{solution:Ex31}
\vspace*{1cm}


\chapter{The fourth chapter}

\begin{exercise}{Ex4}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right)’
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}
\vspace*{1cm}
The solution of the exercise \ref{exercise:Ex4} is in the page \pageref{solution:Ex3}
\vspace*{1cm}




\tcbstoprecording
\newpage
\section{Solutions of the exercices}
\fetchsolutions
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: You're welcome! Happy TeXing!

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: Please consider to accept the given solution

Comment: Sorry it was a "mis-click". I wanted to ensure that the acceptance is well-done ! Many thanks another time for this `Ingenious` and `useful` solution

Comment: Not really in the question, but I'm trying some features to my files, and I want to insert some code between `two solutions` of exercises in the same chapter. How can I do this? Do you think that I must open another question ?

Comment: If I want to make a pagebreak between the solutions of each chapter (but not for the first chapter!), how can I do this? I'm  Sorry to make the question too late, but I thought that it's easy to do... and it's not !

Comment: I was obliged to undo the acceptance because the bug I obtained when I added another chapter to the file, where one can see that the counter of the chapter is on the number of the last chapter... Have you an idea about this behaviour, and a way to solve this?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: You're changing the question. Your question did not contain extra code between two solutions etc. What should this mean: The counter of the chapter is on the number of the last chapter?

Comment: Sorry for the other points, which are changing the question really... My really question is that your solution is acceptable for two chapters not for three or more... I've edited your answer and added the compilation obtained for three chapters where you can see the bug for the chapter two...

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna Please, refine your question, the answer is not the right place for this. If the refinement would result in a substantially changed question, then a follow-up question would be the better way to avoid to invalidate existing answers.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Sorry but I don't know what's "a follow-up question" ! My simple question is that when I add another chapter... something like

 `\chapter{The third chapter}
 \begin{exercise}{Ex3}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
 Just a test
 \tcblower
 Just a test
 \end{exercise}`

then the compilation gives something wrong... I've not tested it before !

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: I think the bug is gone, as well there is a clearpage for the solution chapters and the macro `\extrasolutioncontent` will write its argument unexpanded to the record file. But in the long run your initial setup will bite you since its the wrong approach for such features.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Your solution is really great another time. Many thanks. I've a last question.. In my plan, I'll number my chapters one, two, three... Is there a problem around this ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: In all of the question/answer approaches there must be a decision which content should go expanded (i.e. "frozen") to the solution file and which is transferred unchanged to the solution file. This decision is not made for your setup yet and it is to tedious to pursue this for me because I don't want to update the  solution each time you  have a new feature idea. The more features you add without planning in advance the more your 'building' will turn out to be fragile...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Many thanks another time for all your precious help. It was really helpful for my plan

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Good morning. Would you see my newest question, related to this one. Thanks.

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357224/solutions-of-exercises-produced-with-tcolorbox-numbering-titles

Comment: Would you see this new question, related to his one. Many thanks

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550280/delayed-solutions-with-tcolorbox-problems-for-numbering-figures-with-the-captio