# Solutions of exercises produced with tcolorbox-Numbering titles

Tags: sectioning, tcolorbox, exercises

Using the brilliant macros from the `tcolorbox` package, I write in a book of probability, in every chapter, exercises with solutions. Because I want to write all the solutions together in a chapter, I use the really ingenious macro developed in my question here:

[Solutions of exercises produced with tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350028/solutions-of-exercises-produced-with-tcolorbox/350037#350037)

Now, I use "literal" numbering of the chapters, by using the following macro:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  MACRO FOR LITERAL NUMBERING CHAPTERS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
one\or
two\or
three\or
four\or
five\or
six\or
seven\or
eight\or
nine\or
ten 
\else
I need more words\fi}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %% comment if 'etoolbox' have been loaded before
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  END MACRO FOR LITERAL NUMBERING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

and I want to use the same numbering for the titles of solutions, i.e. something like `Solutions of the exercises of the chapter one`,

`Solutions of the exercises of the chapter two`.. etc.

How can I do this ?

I give here the .tex file used:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% Formatting command as a 'headline' of the solutions of chapter X
\NewDocumentCommand{\solutionchapterformat}{m}{%
  \noindent \bgroup\bfseries Solutions of the exercises of the chapter #1\egroup%
}
\makeatletter

\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \begingroup
%%    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0\relax
%%    \tcbrecord{\string\clearpage}% Write a clearpage after the first chapter for each new chapter
%%    \fi   %% Uncomment these 3 lines if you want a pagebreak between the solutions of 2 chapters
      \c@chapter \numexpr\c@chapter+1% Increase the count register `\@chapter` by one to trick `\thechapter` using the 'correct' chapter number
      \tcbrecord{%
        \solutionchapterformat{\thechapter}}%
      \endgroup
    }{}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\extrasolutioncontent}{+m}{%
  %%\tcbrecord{Extra solution stuff\par}% Remove this later on!
  \tcbrecord{\detokenize{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\fetchsolutions}{%
%For the first chapter
\begingroup
\c@chapter1%
\solutionchapterformat{\thechapter}%
\endgroup% Now get the rest of the stuff
\tcbinputrecords
}
\makeatother



\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
        {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution:#1}}},
    lowerbox=ignored,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=red!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=red!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise:#1} on page~\pageref{exercise:#1}:},
    phantomlabel={solution:#1},
    attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  MACRO FOR LITERAL NUMBERING CHAPTERS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
one\or
two\or
three\or
four\or
five\or
six\or
seven\or
eight\or
nine\or
ten 
\else
I need more words\fi}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %% comment if 'etoolbox' have been loaded before
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  END MACRO FOR LITERAL NUMBERING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{paperwidth=180mm, paperheight=180mm, top=-10mm, bottom=25mm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}

\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( \sin((\sin x)^2) \right)’
=\cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}

\chapter{The second chapter}
\begin{exercise}{Ex2}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right)’
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}

We can write any code between two exercises, directly...

\extrasolutioncontent{We can write too any code between two solutions, by using the ingenious $\backslash$extrasolutioncontent macro developed in the answer...}

\begin{exercise}{Ex3}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right)’
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}

\tcbstoprecording
\newpage
\chapter{Solutions of the exercices}
\fetchsolutions
\end{document}
```

and the compilation of some "interesting" pages...

[image]

[image]

**Edit.** I edit my question to give an answer, using `pgfplots` package, what I gave into an "answer" but the webmasters of the site said that I must edit my question to give an answer, and I do it !

The following commands, in the preamble:

```
\def\mywordscounter{{"zero","one","two","three"}} %%% You can go far from..
%%  Counters of pgf begins always by 0... 
%%  The non-numeric-values must be between " "

% Formatting command as a 'headline' of the solutions of chapter X
\NewDocumentCommand{\solutionchapterformat}{m}{%
\section{Solutions of the exercises of the chapter  \protect\pgfmathparse{\mywordscounter[#1]}\pgfmathresult}%
}
```

enables to do the job.  One can note the command `\protect` added before the `\solutionchapterformat` command, on the suggestion of @ChristianHupfer, which gives the suitable output..

[image]
Unfortunately, there's a problem in my file because its contents are false ! Here is the tex file used after update:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\mywordscounter{{"zero","one","two","three"}} %%% You can go far from..
%%  Counters of pgf begins always by 0... 
%%  The non-numeric-values must be between " "

% Formatting command as a 'headline' of the solutions of chapter X
\NewDocumentCommand{\solutionchapterformat}{m}{%
\section{Solutions of the exercises of the chapter  \protect\pgfmathparse{\mywordscounter[#1]}\pgfmathresult}%
}
\makeatletter

\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \begingroup
%%    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0\relax
%%    \tcbrecord{\string\clearpage}% Write a clearpage after the first chapter for each new chapter
%%    \fi   %% Uncomment these 3 lines if you want a pagebreak between the solutions of 2 chapters
      \c@chapter \numexpr\c@chapter+1% Increase the count register `\@chapter` by one to trick `\thechapter` using the 'correct' chapter number
      \tcbrecord{%
        \solutionchapterformat{\thechapter}}%
      \endgroup
    }{}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\extrasolutioncontent}{+m}{%
  %%\tcbrecord{Extra solution stuff\par}% Remove this later on!
  \tcbrecord{\detokenize{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\fetchsolutions}{%
%For the first chapter
\begingroup
\c@chapter1%
\solutionchapterformat{\thechapter}%
\endgroup% Now get the rest of the stuff
\tcbinputrecords
}
\makeatother



\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
        {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution:#1}}},
    lowerbox=ignored,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=red!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=red!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise:#1} on page~\pageref{exercise:#1}:},
    phantomlabel={solution:#1},
    attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  MACRO FOR LITERAL NUMBERING CHAPTERS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
one\or
two\or
three
\else
I need more words\fi}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %% comment if 'etoolbox' have been loaded before
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  END MACRO FOR LITERAL NUMBERING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{The first chapter}
\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( \sin((\sin x)^2) \right)’
=\cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}

\chapter{The second chapter}
\begin{exercise}{Ex2}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right)’
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}

We can write any code between two exercises, directly...

\extrasolutioncontent{We can write too any code between two solutions, by using the ingenious $\backslash$extrasolutioncontent macro developed in the answer...}

\begin{exercise}{Ex3}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right)’
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}

\tcbstoprecording
\newpage
\fetchsolutions
\end{document}
```

which gives bad output in the contents... "Solutions of the exercises of the chapter 0.017" !!

[image]

What's the problem ?

Comment: I am quite occupied right now (my **paid** daily job at school prevents **unpaid** support round the clock, unfortunately ;-)) others will do the job ;-)

Comment: Luckily I found some time slot

Comment: Many thanks for your disponibility. Texifying is really happy with you, and all the team

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `fmtcount` package and its `\numberstring` and `\numberstringnum` macros to produce the word correspondence of numbers.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% Formatting command as a 'headline' of the solutions of chapter X
\NewDocumentCommand{\solutionchapterformat}{m}{%
  \noindent \bgroup\bfseries Solutions of the exercises of the chapter \numberstringnum{#1}\egroup%
}
\makeatletter

\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \begingroup
%%    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0\relax
%%    \tcbrecord{\string\clearpage}% Write a clearpage after the first chapter for each new chapter
%%    \fi   %% Uncomment these 3 lines if you want a pagebreak between the solutions of 2 chapters
      \c@chapter \numexpr\c@chapter+1% Increase the count register `\@chapter` by one to trick `\thechapter` using the 'correct' chapter number
      \tcbrecord{%
        \solutionchapterformat{\thechapter}}%
      \endgroup
    }{}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\extrasolutioncontent}{+m}{%
  %%\tcbrecord{Extra solution stuff\par}% Remove this later on!
  \tcbrecord{\detokenize{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\fetchsolutions}{%
%For the first chapter
\begingroup
\c@chapter1%
\solutionchapterformat{\thechapter}%
\endgroup% Now get the rest of the stuff
\tcbinputrecords
}
\makeatother



\NewTColorBox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{exercise}{m+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=green!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=green!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Exercise~ \thetcbcounter:},
    label={exercise:#1},
    attach title to upper=\quad,
    after upper={\par\hfill\textcolor{green!40!black}%
        {\itshape Solution on page~\pageref{solution:#1}}},
    lowerbox=ignored,
    savelowerto=solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex,
    record={\string\solution{#1}{solutions/exercise-\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    #2
}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\solution}{mm}{%
    enhanced,
    colframe=red!20!black,
    colback=yellow!10!white,
    coltitle=red!40!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \shade[inner color=red!50!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
            (interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines,step=5mm,yellow!80!black,shift={(interior.north west)}]
            (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    title={Solution of Exercise~\ref{exercise:#1} on page~\pageref{exercise:#1}:},
    phantomlabel={solution:#1},
    attach title to upper=\par,
}{\input{#2}}

\tcbset{no solution/.style={no recording,after upper=}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  MACRO FOR LITERAL NUMBERING CHAPTERS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
one\or
two\or
three
\else
I need more words\fi}

\renewcommand{\words}[1]{\numberstring{chapter}}

\usepackage{etoolbox} %% comment if 'etoolbox' have been loaded before
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  END MACRO FOR LITERAL NUMBERING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{paperwidth=180mm, paperheight=180mm, top=-10mm, bottom=25mm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}

\tcbstartrecording
\begin{exercise}{Ex1}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\sin((\sin x)^2)
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( \sin((\sin x)^2) \right)’
=\cos((\sin x)^2) 2\sin x \cos x.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}

\chapter{The second chapter}
\begin{exercise}{Ex2}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right)’
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}

We can write any code between two exercises, directly...

\extrasolutioncontent{We can write too any code between two solutions, by using the ingenious $\backslash$extrasolutioncontent macro developed in the answer...}

\begin{exercise}{Ex3}[coltitle=cyan!80!black]
Compute the derivative of the following function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1}
\end{equation*}
\tcblower
The derivative is:
\begin{align*}
f’(x) &= \left( (x^2+1) \sqrt{x^4+1} \right)’
= 2x\sqrt{x^4+1} + \frac{2x^3(x^2+1)}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}.
\end{align*}
\end{exercise}

\tcbstoprecording
\newpage
\chapter{Solutions of the exercices}
\fetchsolutions
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ingenious macro as usual. Thanks for this happy TeXifying

Comment: Unfortunately... this was too beautiful !!... I haven't knew what's the `fmtcount` package exactly... when I read the doc, I find this:

Version 1.02 of the fmtcount package now has limited multilingual support.
The following languages are implemented: English, Spanish, Portuguese, French, French (Swiss) and French (Belgian). German support was added in version 1.1.2 Italian support was added in version 1.31. 

But my book is written in arabic, and I thank that there's not a language problem, but there is !

Comment: So have you another solution based on my own counter `words` ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna: Well, there's not a single word in your question that you need support for Arabic language. How many chapters do you plan? If it is limited to 10 etc, the `\words` macro can be used anyway, you have to replace the English expressions by the Arabic ones (including the fonts) -- I neither speak Arabic nor can I read the Arabic 'alphabet' ...

Comment: Ok I haven't say that I use the arabic language because all happens the same stricto sensu else for some things and I don't stop traveling between right-to-left and left-to-right modes, but there's more and more beautiful macros developed for this task...

Comment: Would you see that I edited my question and transform `\words` macro from one to ten... Thank you

Comment: My english is somewhat poor and I don't explain well my ideas.. I plan a book in arabic with 10 chapters. I've edit my question to this task and now the macro `words` goes from one to ten. You say that "the \words macro can be used anyway".. how can it be ? My question is for the english version, and I'll replace the words in the arabic version without any problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can solve my question by using the `pgfplots` package, which enables to define "literal" counters. The following commands in the preamble of my question:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\mywordscounter{{"zero","one","two","three"}} %%% You can go far from..
%%  Counters of pgf begins always by 0... 
%%  The non-numeric-values must be between " "

% Formatting command as a 'headline' of the solutions of chapter X
\NewDocumentCommand{\solutionchapterformat}{m}{%
\noindent\bgroup\bfseries Solutions of the exercises of the chapter  \pgfmathparse{\mywordscounter[#1]}\pgfmathresult\egroup%
}
```

gives the suitable behaviour. Thanks to Christian Hupfer for its original beautiful macro.

But there's a final last problem !! If I want my output title of solutions in format of section. If I use instead the command:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\solutionchapterformat}{m}{%
\section{Solutions of the exercises of the chapter  \pgfmathparse{\mywordscounter[#1]}\pgfmathresult}%
}
```

I obtain the error message:

`! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line ...`

What am I doing wrong here ?

[image]

Comment: You should ask a follow-up question for your final problem and edit your answer. It shouldn't ask questions but should rather be a self-contained answer to the above question. (I accidently flagged this as *not an answer*. Sorry…)

Comment: You need to protect the command `\pgfmathparse`, i.e. `\section{....\protect\pgfmathparse{...}}` etc.